# Could not able to get X509Certificate2 certificate by code C#

Tags: c#-4.0, x509certificate2

I want to find certificate from my store but using following code i could not able to get certificate. It always return null.

[image: code to get certificate by thumbprint]

What's wrong with my code?

**Update:**

I have copied my certificate thumbprint by exploring store object and compare it with my thumbprint string and it return false! I think issue of interpreting string in VS2010 IDE or copy paste problem you can see that below in fig. because of this it should ignore the certificate from the list. Have anyone faced this type of issue before?

[image]

Comment: Your store location is CurrentUser.  Are you sure that the location the certificate was stored in matches the CurrentUser location?

Comment: Yes i am sure that it is located there, please see my updated question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well the certificate collection is empty since there's no certificate with that thumbprint.
Check:

- that the certificate is present in your current user
- that the certificate is stored in the personal folder

Try:

- using mmc to verify the above things
- using `X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);`

**Edit:**

Does the following return anything useful:

```
X509Certificate2Collection col = store.Certificates;

foreach (var currCert in col)
{
     var currThumbprint = currCert.Thumbprint;
     if (thumbprint.ToUpperInvariant() == currThumbprint)
     {
         x509Certificate2= currCert;
         break;
     }
}
```

Comment: Yes i am sure that it is located there, please see my updated question

Comment: Will you try the code above - it's a simple custom FindByThumbprint

Comment: I have tried above code still it skip although certificate thumbprint is same. very strand issue!.

Comment: Can you write a quick char to char comparison of the two thumbprint string to see where it fails? Can't think of anything else - maybe it's a matter of encoding ( doubt that ) or some character

Comment: Yes it should be because of that when i comparing this 2 string it return false in VS2010 IDE.

Comment: Well yeah - of course it fails, but there could be a hidden character somewhere - like end of line or something similar - if you can understand where it fails you can fix the string you search with.

Comment: Hey solved that issue when i have written that thumbprint manually without copy/paste.

Comment: Same happened to me. I was doing copy-paste of thumbprint from certificate properties to C# source, and removing spaces. After I typed the entire string manually, it worked. I still cannot believe!

Comment: Upon further research, I found that the C# source file contains the [left-to-right control character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-to-right_mark). This character is not displayed by Visual Studio even with "View White Space" on. The trick to detect it is to go to beginning of line, then hit Right Arrow. The cursor should move on each hit. If it doesn't move, there's a hidden character. Works at least on VS2012.

Answer (score 2):

There might be invisible/zero length chars in your thumbprint especially at the beginning or at the end. Measure the length of thumbprint you supplied ("35ED.." ). It should be greater than what appears.