# C# private key is missing - certificate is installed with private key

Tags: c#, asp.net

iam writing a code to access a service on another server

the certificate was installed with the private key on my server

when i run the test

```
if (cer.HasPrivateKey)
            {
                Response.Write("OK");

            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("Nooo");
            }
```

i got ok = so the certificate has a private key

but when i run the whole code

```
 try
        {


            //  ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            HttpWebRequest httpWReq =
                 (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://gw.bisan.com/api/apdemo_6");

            Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
            string postData = @"{""user"":""cube"",""password"":""258970"",""command"":""table"",""table"":""currency"",""filters"":[{""field"":""code"",""operation"":""!\u003d"",""value"":""01""}],""fields"":[""symbol"",""rate""]}";
            byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);

            httpWReq.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
            httpWReq.Method = "POST";
            httpWReq.ContentType = "application/json";//charset=UTF-8";


            var certificate = @"\www.cube-its.com.pfx";
            X509Certificate2 cer = new X509Certificate2(new X509Certificate2(Server.MapPath(certificate), "XXXX"));

            httpWReq.ClientCertificates.Add(cer);

            Response.Write(cer.PrivateKey.ToString());
            if (cer.HasPrivateKey)
            {
                Response.Write("OK");

            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("Nooo");
            }

            httpWReq.ContentLength = data.Length;



            Stream stream = httpWReq.GetRequestStream();
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            stream.Close();

            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWReq.GetResponse();

            string s = response.ToString();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            String jsonresponse = "";
            String temp = null;
            while ((temp = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                jsonresponse += temp;
            }

            Response.Write("Json Response : " + jsonresponse);

        }
        catch (WebException ex1)
        {
            { Response.Write("Exception 2 : " + ex1.Message); }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { Response.Write("Exception : " + ex.Message); }
```

i always got  server error 400 bad request

when i cantact the company they say that the request is missing the private key

so what shall i do 'thanx

Comment: I hope that's not the real password of the .pfx file

Comment: If the certificate is installed, why don't you use the Certificate Store?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10652073/could-not-able-to-get-x509certificate2-certificate-by-code-c-sharp loads from store

Comment: the problem is the certificate is installed on the hosting server it was not me who isntaled the certicate , so is it the same method?